# asmcmd returns with error " Can't locate loadable object for module DBI in @INC"

Tags: linux, perl, grid

[grid@srv1 ~]$ asmcmd

Can't locate loadable object for module DBI in @INC (@INC contains: /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/perl/lib/5.14.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/perl/lib/5.14.1 /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/perl/lib/site_perl/5.14.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/perl/lib/site_perl/5.14.1 /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/lib /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/lib/asmcmd /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/rdbms/lib/asmcmd /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/perl/lib/site_perl/5.14.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/perl/lib/site_perl/5.14.1 /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/perl/lib/5.14.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/perl/lib/5.14.1 .) at /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/perl/lib/5.14.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DBI.pm line 263
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/perl/lib/5.14.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DBI.pm line 263.
Compilation failed in require at /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/lib/asmcmdshare.pm line 320.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/lib/asmcmdshare.pm line 320.
Compilation failed in require at /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/bin/asmcmdcore line 183.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/bin/asmcmdcore line 183.

Answer (score 0):

install DBI module using cpan or ppm in case of Activestate.